# 2005 Chrysler PT Cruiser - Check Engine Light is on and has started regularly sputtering

Tags: chrysler, pt-cruiser, p0340, p0455

I went to Autozone and the codes are

- P0340 - Cam Shaft Position Sensor
- P0455 - Evaporative Emissions Problem

I don't know a lot about cars. What should I do?

Comment: You can usually Google trouble codes to get a description of the code. I've edited your post with my results from searching. It doesn't work for every make/model, as manufacturers tend to make up their own hard to decipher codes, but there is a standard.

Comment: Could you provide more words about your problem?  Right now, it's difficult for us to provide much of substance other than what those codes are.  For example, try to describe "sputtering" and how "regularly" does it happen?

Answer (score 3):

These are two very separate problems, though you could try just having the codes cleared first (since they have been read, hopefully they have already been cleared). With the brevity of the question, I'll assume you did this and these are the two codes which have remained. Soooo ...

The P0340 has to do with the [cam position sensor](http://www.obd-codes.com/p0340). This seems like a fairly common problem on PT Cruisers. With this problem the car would go into what is called "limp home mode", where the engine will max out at about 2,500rpm. Sputtering and such seems fairly common here, also. Replacement of the sensor is relatively easy and could be accomplished by anybody with a good mechanical sense about them in about 10-20 minutes.

The P0455 code has to do with a [evaporative emission control system leak](http://www.samarins.com/diagnose/p0455.html). This problem is a little harder to diagnose exactly what is going on. The possible causes here are:

- Gas cap left open or not closed properly
- Faulty gas cap or damaged gas cap seal
- Faulty or stuck-open vent control valve (could also be called vent control solenoid)
- Damaged or cracked charcoal canister
- Cracked or disconnected EVAP hose
- Stuck open purge valve (solenoid)